# DOCX to PDF conversion using Opensagres and Apache poi results in missing symbols when running on Docker

Tags: java, pdf, apache-poi, docx

I am using this code to convert docx to pdf:

```
try {
        PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
        PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(firstDoc, out, options);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Conversion failed.");
    }
    return prepareResponseEntity(out);
```

It works well on Windows, but when it's run on docker, the conversion skips symbols like "ąčęėįšųūž" and cyrillic.

I tried embedding fonts into the template. Changing the .docx template to Liberation fonts "sans" and importing its' ttf files, but nothing works. I can't install Microsoft fonts, because this app is used for commercial purposes.

What are my options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
try {
        PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
        options.fontProvider((familyName, encoding, size, style, color) -> {
            try {
                BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont("fonts/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
                return new Font(baseFont, size, style, color);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Font was not found" + e);
            }
        });
        PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(firstDoc, out, options);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Conversion failed");
    }
    return prepareResponseEntity(out);
```

You also need to add your font .ttf file to the resource folder and it works!